# Illustrator CS6: Shape tool draws path instead of shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Every time, I try to draw a shape with for example the rectangle tool. Illustrator creates a path instead of a shape (as you can see on the image).

[image: illustrator screenshot]

The shape tool doesn't render the rectangle as `<rectangle>` but as `<path>`. Is it possible to change this setting?

Comment: Illustrator is a vector software, it works in paths. What **do** you want it to do? (What do you mean by "shape")

Answer (score 0):

This is **exactly** how Illustrator is *supposed* to function. You are perhaps confusing Illustrator with Photoshop.

There is nothing wrong or incorrect about your screen shot.

You may benefit from reviewing some [**basic tutorials**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustration-techniques.html) regarding Illustrator.

The actual name of the object layer created depends upon the ***Illustrator version***.

- In CS6, it's just `<path>`
- in CC2017+  it's `<Rectangle>`

Looking at the screenshot, it appears some version between CS6 and CC2017 is in use (Perhaps CC2014)... so it may be reading `<path>` correctly.

Note that the object layer name really is *inconsequential*. It doesn't alter anything other than the name itself.

Comment: There is something wrong in the image, the sublayer instead of being called **Rectangle** as usual when creating a rectangle, is named **Path** (Pfad in German). It's not a normal behavior and I think is what the OP is asking.

Comment: Looks like CS6 to me (just based off the color of the icon)

Comment: @WELZ Actually it was the icon color in the top left that lead me to believe it was CC2014 or 2015. CS6 was a greyscale icon. :)

Comment: @Scott [nope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oelgP.png)

Comment: @WELZ errr.. [Yup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWouK.png) `:)` But it does change to the orange if you use the dark interface... so we are both right. i never use the dark and didn't check that `:)`

Comment: Also note that you can *easily, quickly* ***rename*** *any* path, entity, group or layer in an Illustrator document within the Layer palette, and many of us think it best practise to have *specific nomenclature* - especially for larger illustrations. I occasionally work on illustrative site plans whose vectors start off in CAD - and in many cases you can end up with 12+ layer, and thousands of entities to manage in such a file - and you only have to do *one* of those, ***once***, and then have to *revise it*, to learn that having everything named <path> is counter-productive. Name your stuff!